# Cursor returning only one row

Tags: arrays, sqlite, arraylist, cursor, row

I'm doing a check in order to get my favorite own Promotions objects into an array.
I tried to do this (from my PromotionsBDD class which controls my Table Promotions from my SQLite Database):

```
public ArrayList<Promotion> getListPromotionsFavorites()
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] {"ID", "RATING", "TITLE", "COMPANY_ID","AVAILABLEDATE", "DESCRIPTION", "SETONFAVORITE"};

        Cursor objCursor = bdd.query(TABLE_PROMOTIONS, columns,null,null,null,null,null,null);//requete de récupération de la liste

        int id = objCursor.getColumnIndex("ID");
        int rating = objCursor.getColumnIndex("RATING");
        int title = objCursor.getColumnIndex("TITLE");
        int companyid = objCursor.getColumnIndex("COMPANY_ID");
        int availabledate = objCursor.getColumnIndex("AVAILABLEDATE");
        int description = objCursor.getColumnIndex("DESCRIPTION");
        int setonfavorite = objCursor.getColumnIndex("SETONFAVORITE");

        ArrayList<Promotion> promoFavoriteArray = new ArrayList<Promotion>();
        objCursor.moveToFirst();// position sur la première ligne

        if (objCursor != null) 
        {
            if (objCursor.isFirst())
            {
                int i = 0;
                do 
                {
                    String resultsetonfavorite = objCursor.getString(setonfavorite);
                    if (resultsetonfavorite.equals("true"))
                    {
                        i++;
                        String resultid = objCursor.getString(id);
                        String resultrating = objCursor.getString(rating);
                        String resultitle = objCursor.getString(title);
                        int resultcompanyid = objCursor.getInt(companyid);
                        String resultavailbledate = objCursor.getString(availabledate);
                        String resultdescription = objCursor.getString(description);

                        Promotion promo = new Promotion(resultid, resultrating, resultitle, 
                                resultcompanyid,resultavailbledate,resultdescription, resultsetonfavorite);
                        promoFavoriteArray.add(promo);
                        objCursor.moveToNext();//positionnement sur le suivant
                    }
                    else
                        i++;
                }
                while(objCursor.isLast());
            }
        }

    objCursor.deactivate();
    objCursor.close();
    return promoFavoriteArray;
}
```

And it is only returning me an array of the top row..
Someone knows how doing ?

Comment: should the loop not end with "while (!objCursor.IsLast)" ?  Also where do you advance the cursor ?

Comment: here : objCursor.moveToNext(); into the "do" expression

Comment: ok - yes.  But '(objCursor.isLast())' is false on the first iteration, unless there is only one record.  If there is only one record you will go into an infinite loop, if there are 2 or more records it will exit after the first one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether has record in the table. You can use this.

```
Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from table limit 1", null);
        if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
```

It will return only to find on record.

Answer (score 0):

change the line

```
while(objCursor.isLast());
```

to

```
while(!objCursor.isLast());
```

Comment: @eento - no further comment?  Was my answer correct ? If so I would appreciate acceptance of the answer